# Create a border-less table which can be pasted in Word

Tags: html, css, ms-word

I'm struggling to find out what is the right format to create a border-less table which pasted in word will look like below:

```html
<strong>Foo</strong>

<ol>
  <li value="0">This is zero.</li>
  <li value="7">Another number.</li>
  <li value="42">Favorite number.</li>
</ol>

<strong>Bar</strong>

<ol>
  <li value="0">This is zero.</li>
  <li value="7">Another number.</li>
  <li value="42">Favorite number.</li>
</ol>
```

The layout I need is:

```
Some strong text here

    0. Right aligned numbers on the left
   42. And text on the right side
    7. With some padding on the left.
```

Problems

- **Using a list like above**
  When pasting this in Word (I'm actually using Apple Pages), it ends with ordered list starting with `1`.
- **Using a table**
  I tried using a `<table>`. Even it's borderless in the browser, borders are added in the text processor (Apple Pages in my case)
- **Using Divs**
  When using divs, I cannot control the width and alignment of the first column.

What is the right thing to do in this case? I just need something pastable looking like this in Word:

> [image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the *ordered-list* element (`ol`) to an *unordered-list* element (`ul`) (to circumvent the default list numbering of the editor application or programme) with an inline style declaring the `list-style` property with the value of `decimal`, then pasting it in the document while retaining the *source formatting* (`Ctrl+V+K`) or *merging* the formatting (`Ctrl+V+M`)? e.g: `<ul style="list-style: decimal;">...</ul>`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I didn't, but will I be able to set custom values in that case?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Any ideas? :D

Comment: Yes, all my testing indicated this (the `value` attributes are included when pasting with source formatting), you should have no problem specifying your own values this way.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError So, can you post an answer? :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Paste Options:**

Consider pasting the copied markup with *Source Formatting* (`Ctrl+V+K`) or *Merged Formatting* (`Ctrl+V+M`) to retain the formatting specified by the source.

#### List Items

**Circumvent default Word editor list numbering**

To negate the default formatting Word editing applications or programmes may include for ordered list items, consider changing the ordered-list element (`ol`) to an unordered-list element (`ul`) with an *inline style* declaring the `list-style` property with the value of `decimal`, e.g:

```
<ul style="list-style: decimal;">
  <li value="0">This is zero.</li>
  <li value="7">Another number.</li>
  <li value="42">Favorite number.</li>
</ul>
```

This should allow you to retain any custom values specified for the attribute properties `value` on given list-items.

#### Table Elements

**x2 Column layout with custom values specified in first column**

A similar output should be achievable using `table` layouts, e.g:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td align="right">0</td>
      <td>This is zero.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td align="right">7</td>
      <td>Another number.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td align="right">42</td>
      <td>Favorite number.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```html
<strong>Foo</strong><sup>unordered list</sup>

<ul style="list-style: decimal">
  <li value="0">This is zero.</li>
  <li value="7">Another number.</li>
  <li value="42">Favorite number.</li>
</ul>

<strong>Bar</strong><sup>x2 column table</sup>

<table>
  <tr>
      <td align="right">0</td>
      <td>This is zero.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td align="right">7</td>
      <td>Another number.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td align="right">42</td>
      <td>Favorite number.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Apple Pages or Google Docs. If it works in Word, it should be fine for now (I cannot test it tho because I'm on Mac). If you have any ideas how to extend this, I'd be very thankful. Thanks! :)